# Windows replacing Gnu/Linux partition with drive letter

Tags: windows, dual-boot, solus

I recently moved to Microsoft's Windows 10 because of some apps that wine wouldn't run. I consider myself a fairly knowledgeable Gnu/Linux user. I am trying to set up a dual-boot with windows 10 and solus. These are the steps I followed:

1. I shrank the C:\ partition of the drive, to allow space for Gnu/Linux. (The new partition had 160 gigs).
2. I created a bootable Solus USB with balenaEtcher.
3. I restarted my computer, pressed f2 to enter the BIOS, and selected the USB as the first boot option. I applied these settings and the computer automatically restarted and booted into the live Solus.
4. I went into the KDEPartition Manager, and formatted the 160gb partition into ext4.
5. I applied this, restarted the computer, and started the Installation Manager
6. Upon reaching the "Where should we install?" menu, I selected the "custom" option.
7. I selected my 160gb volume to be the "/". *This may be wrong. I have never installed using the custom menu. I might have need to choose this to be "/home", but no tutorials mentioned this. Also, the 160gb volume showed up as 170gb.*
8. I spammed through the rest of the options, such as username/passwd.
9. I restarted the computer, removing the USB.
10. The computer booted into Windows 10.
11. I though it might be a boot order issue, so I checked the BIOS. There was no Gnu/Linux option. There were 3 Windows options, but that is the way my computer has been for a while, even when using Gnu/Linux. nevertheless, I tried each of them, but all of them predictably booted into Windows.
12. I got a new installation USB with a new iso and tried steps 2-9 again. 10 and 11 were the results, again.
13. I entered Windows' partition manager to see what's what, and windows had replaced that new partition with the drive letter D:\

I am not sure why this is doing this. I am on a Dell Precision Tower 3420, which originally had Windows 10 pre-installed. The default barracuda HHD was too slow, so i used a 120gb SSD with Ubuntu instead. I bought a 500gb m.2 SSD and transfered the old SSD to the m.2. I needed Windows, so I cloned the original HHD to the m.2, wiping Gnu/Linux. Then I tried the aforementioned steps. I do *not* want to use a VM, so please do not include answers involving that. Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Step 8, at the end of the installation process, grub may ask if it should install to `/dev/sda` or /dev/sdaX` (where `X` is a digit in the range `1`-`9`). The default on Debian is `/dev/sdaX` but it should be `/dev/sda`.

Comment: "_Also, the 160gb volume showed up as 170gb_". That's because you're misusing the units. There is no such thing as "gb", only "Gb" (gigabit), "GB" (gigabyte), or "GiB" (gibibyte - yes, really). GB is based on powers of 10, GiB is based on powers of 2; for large-ish values they're significantly different. To add to the confusion some technologies use GB when they mean GiB.

Comment: @roaima Sorry. I was not aware of that. I just saw a GB, or maybe a gb after the units, so that is what I wrote down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you only have to define root partition for "/" and maybe swap. Also standard install recommendation is Linux first then all others. Also you are selecting for format in EXT4 for "/"? Grub should be installed to which ever drive is set as 1st boot drive in your BIOS.

I made a mistake like @roalma mentioned. I think I rebooted while holding down the Shift or ESC key and was able to view grub boot option.
Once you get back into Edit `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and after you save `sudo update-grub` but I'm sure you knew that part.

You also might have assigned the USB drive for grub install.

Comment: Yes, I did on accident. Thanks so much, and sorry for asking a question with an answer I could find if I tried hard enough.